# wifi setting missing - No additional drivers available. -Network UNCLAIMED

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I'm a new user of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460s. I have a problem with the Network settings, since there not appear any icon about the wifi and I can only use the wired connection. I noticed that no additional drivers are available and also the Network is UNCAIMED.

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1000000-f1001fff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eth0
   version: 21
   serial: 50:7b:9d:dc:c9:fe
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt       10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=10.0.28.132 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:122 memory:f1200000-f121ffff

lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)

uname -r
3.19.0-64-generic
```

What do you suggest to do? Should I install the drivers? And how? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and also:`uname -r` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel 8260 adapter is not supported by the 3.19 Linux kernel.

You installed Ubuntu 14.04.3, not 14.04.4 with the 4.2 kernel.

There are two options to get Wi-Fi working:

1. Upgrade the kernel in your 14.04 installation by running in terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
   ```
2. Upgrade your system to 16.04 or do a fresh install of 16.04.

Comment: No third party module? huh..

Comment: @Pilot6 Great! I updated the kernel and all my problems are solved! Thank you a lot!